# Call function on click instead of onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function which run when loading the page

```
                function sssssss(page){
                loading_show();                 
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

I need to call this function also onClick let's say when clicking button id="go"
I have tried by adding

```
$('#go').live('click',function sssssss(page){... }
```

it gives me an error.

How to call this function on Click?

Comment: And the error would be..?

Comment: it doesn t load anything

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? What version of jQuery are you using? [`.live()` was removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/), superceded by [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: im running jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do this instead:**

```
$('#go').click(function (){
 sssssss(page);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('#go').live('click', function () {
    sssssss(page);
})
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

You should use,

```
$('body').on('click', '#go', function () {
    sssssss(page);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

API of Jquery says: **As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.**

this should work:

```
 $('#go').on('click', sssssss(page));
```

You can see examples here:

[Api Jquery method On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)